# Better approach to do this

Tags: python, python-2.7

How we can approach this function in a better way

or

How can we make it more efficient

or

Optimize the code :

```
def is_interesting(tt):
    return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') is not None and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tt.get('script') is not None` part is redundant, because `None` is not in the next tuple either.

Your test is otherwise plenty efficient; Python will not evaluate the second expression if the first is `False` already.

```
def is_interesting(tt):
    return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno')
```

Demo:

```
>>> def is_interesting(tt):
...     return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno')
... 
>>> is_interesting({'target_type': 42})
False
>>> is_interesting({'target_type': 670})
False
>>> is_interesting({'target_type': 670, 'script': ''})
False
>>> is_interesting({'target_type': 670, 'script': 'abc'})
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but their are the chances that we can get tt.get('script') as empty. Hence added tt.get('script') is not None.

Comment: @user3437078: yes, and `None` is *not* in the tuple of `('abc', 'syz', 'mno')`. `None in ('abc', 'syz', 'mno')` is False *anyway*.

Comment: if tt.get('script') is having none/empty value, it is showing me an error at execution " return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno')
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand  "  Hence I added this statement to cope up with empty value of tt.get('script')

Comment: @user3437078: **Did you try it**? `None` and `''` are not values in that tuple, so `False` is returned.

Comment: yeah I am getting this error, this is reason to ask this

Comment: @user3437078 That error would be raised if you had: `None in 'abc'` using python3. Are you sure you are running *exactly* the code above?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is exactly same as Martijin.

```
def is_interesting(tt):
    return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno')
```

I just want to answer this:

> " return tt['target_type'] == 670 and tt.get('script') in ('abc','syz','mno') TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand " Hence I added this statement to cope up with empty value of tt.get('script')

Example:

```
>>> {'foo':'bar'}.get('notexist') in ('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType

>>> {'foo':'bar'}.get('notexist') in ('foo',)
False

>>> {'foo':'bar'}.get('notexist') in ['foo']
False
```

Explanation: the first example, there's only one element in the (), so ('foo') actually returns you 'foo' -- a string; the 2nd and 3rd can ensure you get a tuple/list. Put a comma after the single element inside parentheses is the way to get a way with one element. I guess this's what you encountered.

Comment: Thanks I think I am doing the mistake what you had suggested here. Thanks for the help

Comment: The other way this could come up is `tt.get('script') in ('abc' 'syz' 'mno')` (ie, forgetting all of the commas), which triggers Python's string literal concatenation - so it parses as one long string rather than a tuple of three strings.